# Enforce max allowed processing time when calling listeners

Tags: java, multithreading

I notify some listeners in a loop.

```
for (Iterator it = listeners.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    MyListener l = (MyListener) it.next();
    l.notifyEvent(event);
}
```

I have no idea what the listener is doing within the notify method - it might take very long or be blocked waiting for input. 
To guarantee the responsiveness of the system, I want to allow for a maximum processing time before going on with the next listener.

What is an accepted pattern to guarantee a max processing time for a method call?

I think of two possibilities:

- spawn a new thread for the notification. If it doesn't return in time, make a new thread and process the next listener with it. When the first one eventually returns, just let it die . Can you give code examples for this strategy?
- send an interrupt to the currently processing listener thread and hope that this makes it return.

Any other ideas or best practices?

PS: I use the java.util.concurrent backport with Java 1.4, so j.u.c constructs are available.

Edit: here's a solution I developed. It uses ExecutorServices so it is a bit heavy to achieve this simple purpose. It uses only one additional thread until that thread gets stuck in a listener. It then spawns a new thread (in the new ExecutorService) to go on working with the next listeners. Note: this solution is not thread-safe nor concurrency capable. Only one thread should call doNotify()

```
private final Queue listeners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
private final long timeout;
private final TimeUnit unit;
private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

public void doNotify(){
    for (Iterator it = listeners.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        final MyListener l = (MyListener) it.next();
        Future future = threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                l.notifyEvent();
            }
        });
        try {
            future.get(timeout, unit); // wait for task to be executed
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // ignore for now
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // ignore for now
        } catch (TimeoutException e1) {
            threadPool.shutdown(); // pool accepts no new tasks, and will exit when done
            threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); // make new thread for next listener
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the listeners are independent, and if you don't care about their "responses" or any callbacks, you could simply spawn a thread for each listener that notifies the listener. If you do want to give them *some* time to finish before you go on, you could call [`Thread.join(millis)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) on each thread a timeout.

If you care about the maximum number of threads, you could use the same approach but with a thread pool instead. However then you're in a bit of trouble if the number of "blocking" listeners exceeds the number of threads in your thread pool.

Keep in mind that `Thread.stop` is deprecated for [good reasons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will build on that. For a lot of listeners, your solution will spawn a lot of threads which I want to avoid. A new thread should be made only if needed (assuming, normal listener reply in time).

Comment: @Philipp, well, that's why I mentioned thread pools as an alternative design choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification: if you dont control the code of MyListener (even if you spawn a new thread) you will never be able to be control the time it waste. There is no way to force a thread to shutdown or interrupt, or to be sure he will respect your allowed time.

Comment: *There is no way to force a thread to shutdown*, Well, there is the `Thread.stop` method, but it should be used with extreme care (if at all).

Comment: Thread.stop is deprecated because if you 'kill' a thread and dont know how to free the resources it was using you may have a leak of whatever. If you dont control the code of MyListener and kill the thread you cannot predict what you may lose. And it should be something important :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't control the code in the listeners, you should keep in mind that most listeners will be written with the assumption that they're running on the event dispatch thread.  Running them on a background thread may lead them to make calls into AWT or Swing methods that aren't thread-safe.

If this is restricted to a particular `MyListener` interface which you control, then you'll at least want to add a caveat to its javadoc that `MyListener.notify()` is not guaranteed to be invoked on the EDT.

Comment: *"most listeners will be written with the assumption that they're running on the event dispatch thread"* ... Are you assuming he is talking about AWT/Swing listeners?

Comment: My question is about threading in general not Swing/AWT. If it is of any importance for him, the listener can check what thread calls it before doing anything.

Comment: Okay, sorry.  I assumed if you were looking to avoid blocking a thread and listeners were involved, odds were good that the thread in question was the EDT and the listeners were AWT/Swing event listeners.  Sorry for jumping to conclusions.